# Highlighting the top and bottom of a matrix

Tags: matrices, highlighting, tikz-matrix

[image]

I want to be able to make that kind of triangles like in the image. I hope you can help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way using `tikzmark`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \hat{A}=\begin{pmatrix}
        a_{11} &\tikzmark{tl}a_{12} & a_{13} & \dots\tikzmark{tr}\\
        \tikzmark{a21}a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & \dots\\
        a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & \dots\tikzmark{dots}\\
        \tikzmark{bl}\vdots & \vdots & \vdots\tikzmark{br} & \ddots
      \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw [blue] ([xshift=-6pt,yshift=-2pt]pic cs:bl) --  ([yshift=10pt]pic cs:a21) -- ([xshift=25pt,yshift=-2pt]pic cs:br) -- cycle;
\draw [red] ([xshift=-10pt,yshift=6pt]pic cs:tl) --  ([yshift=6pt]pic cs:tr) -- ([yshift=-10pt]pic cs:dots) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fascinating! Thank's so much. You have helped me a lot with this code. Thanks

Comment: @Kale_1729 You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

With `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\hat{A} = 
\begin{pNiceMatrix}
  a_{11} &a_{12} & a_{13} & \dots\\
  a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & \dots\\
  a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & \dots\\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} [rounded corners]
  \draw [blue] ([xshift=4pt,yshift=3pt]2-|1) 
               |- ([xshift=-4pt,yshift=3pt]last-|last) -- cycle ; 
  \draw [red] ([xshift=-5pt,yshift=-3pt]1-|2) -| ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=-5pt]4-|last) -- cycle ;
  \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations because of the PGF/Tikz nodes.

[image: Output of the above code]